# npm ERR! ENETUNREACH when i try to install dependencies using " npm i "

Tags: npm-install, npm-start, npm-package

everything was working fine but yesterday when I try to create a new project using npx create-react-app appname OR try to run current project by installing dependencies ' npm i ' i face this error.

```
npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/body-parser failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 0.0.31.144:80   

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\(.log file address)
```

**What I tried:**

- Check your internet connection: working fine
- clear cache and Retry the installation: I tried but not working same error
- Firewall settings: I also enabled the public and private node.exe file from Windows Defender Firewall settings
- remove your package-lock.json: remove your node-modules folder and your package-lock.json file and run a fresh npm install command.
- reinstalling nodeJs: i just delete and reinstall nodejs 21.7.1 but no improvements
- Check npm Configuration: using 'npm config list' and found https-proxy = "http://8080/" someone suggest me to try `npm config set proxy http://<proxy-host>:<proxy-port>` then i use host=localhost and port=8080 by doing this i face error

  ```
  npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
  npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
  npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/whatwg-url/-/whatwg-url-11.0.0.tgz failed, reason: 
  npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> and further errors.
  ```

  so I just set it back to `npm config set https-proxy = http://8080/`

Any ideas what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm not a npm expert, but you probably don't want "npm config set proxy" unless you are sure that you actually connect to the Internet through a proxy server.  Proxies are typically used in larger corporate environments for security and web content filtering.

Comment: Hi James 
I wanted to express my sincere appreciation for your advice regarding the proxy server configuration.
Before you even mentioned it, I had already removed the proxy server settings, and I'm pleased to inform you that the issue has been resolved successfully. Your insight proved to be instrumental, and I'm grateful for your prompt assistance.

Thank you once again for sharing your knowledge and for your willingness to help!